# How to create a destroy action in rails 4 to remove files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using refile gem for multiple uploads. Images are showing up nicely. I want to create a destroy action to show under the images using `link_to`. **How should I write my destroy action and what should be the path at `link to`?** Thank you!

show.html.erb

```
<% @post.images.each do |i| %>
 <%= attachment_image_tag(i, :file, :fill, 350, 350, format: "jpg") %>
 <%= link_to 'Delete', **?????**, method: :detele %>
<% end %>
```

I can delete the 2nd image from my first post using console like this `p=Post.first.images.find 2` then `p.destroy` .

My post and image model are

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  attachment :file
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_attachments_for :images, attachment: :file, append: true
end
```

config/routes.rb

`Rails.application.routes.draw do
   resources :posts do
     resources :images
   end
  root 'posts#index'
 end`

Answer (score 1):

```
<% @post.images.each do |i| %>
  <%= attachment_image_tag(i, :file, :fill, 350, 350, format: "jpg") %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete', post_image_path(@post.id, i.id), method: :detele %>
<% end %>
```

Just paste your image path. If your routes configured correctly, this will be enough.

**UPDATED**

Your routes should be like this

```
resources :posts do
  resources :images
end
```

Comment: `resources :images`Thanks. I tried earlier but it gives me routing error. I have both posts_controller and images_controller. I have  `resources :posts` and  `resources :images` in my routes.rb . I guess images_controller is not useful here as i'm using refile gem attachments.
 Any suggestion?

Comment: Thanks but still no route match! If it helps... I can delete the 2nd image from my first post using console like this `p=Post.first.images.find 2` then `p.destroy` .

Comment: Show your `config/routes.rb`

Comment: will update in the qsn
`Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts do
    resources :images
  end
  root 'posts#index' 
end `

Comment: Yes. I tried to follow you and used it in my routes as you suggested. Added the file at the end of the question now. But it's still the same. error: No route matches [POST] "/images"

Comment: getting error. may be getting closer. `  No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"images", :id=>nil, :post_id=>#<Image id: 1, file_id: "34f0912ef9367d74744780ee5b97bfbcdc5b6ae9d8e1b0114c...", post_id: 1, created_at: "2015-09-08 07:01:50", updated_at: "2015-09-08 07:01:50">} missing required keys: [:id] `

Comment: Still an error No route matches [POST] "/posts/1/images/1" . Thanks though!

Comment: dont forget security ! current_user.images.find(params[:id]).destroy!

Comment: Ya sure. Thanks! but I need to make it work at first ! :\ @huanson

Comment: I figured it out. I had to update my images_controller